# Convert reference to a specific style online

Tags: citation-style, reference-managers

Is there any online tool to convert references to a specific style (of a journal)? Preferably, it is better that no Latex knowledge is needed!

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear from your question (and perhaps you could clarify it) exactly what you are wanting to convert ***from***. I think it's highly unlikely that there is something that will convert from any arbitrary format that you choose as input. That said, however, there are several things that might help you.

- If you can locate the reference on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/), then you will find
  that there is a link labelled *Cite* below each reference that is
  returned from a search. When you click the Cite link, you will find
  the reference you searched for formatted for MLA, APA, Chicago, Harvard and Vancouver
  styles. In addition, there are methods for exporting the citation to
  Bibtex, Endnote, Refman, and
  RefWorks. One or other of those formats can also be used to import
  into [Zotero](https://zotero.org).
- If you know the [DOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) of the paper you want to cite, then you can use [Crossscite.org](https://citation.crosscite.org/) to give you the citation in your desired format
- If you locate the paper online, even if access is behind
  a paywall, you will frequently find that there is a pre-formatted
  citation waiting for you. For example, if you look at this paper
  called "Interactive Data Exploration with Smart Drill-Down" ([DOI
  10.1109/TKDE.2017.2685998](https://doi.org/10.1109/TKDE.2017.2685998)) you will find that there is a link on the page that is provided by the publisher to help you. The link is
  in a box saying "Cite this", and when you click the link, you are
  given the same kind of options as in Google Scholar. Not every publisher provides such a simple citation option, but many do.
- Finally, it
  isn't clear whether you are already using a citation manager such as
  [Zotero](https://zotero.org). If not, then even if you do not need all the features that
  Zotero offers, you will find that it can import references from a
  host of sources and then format them into almost any journal format
  you can imagine.

**Added later**: If you have many references to format, and you don't like the idea of installing and managing a citation manager on your own computer, consider just creating a Zotero account. Your online Zotero library (up to 300 Mb) will be managed for you, and you will be able to get it to display a correctly formatted reference for most journals.

Comment: +1 for Zotero, reference managers are such a boon. And you can disable syncing files to the library, making the list of references effectively infinitely large.